# How do we get/define filters in convolutional neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

How do I obtain filters from convolutional neural network(CNN)? My idea is something like this: do random images of the input images (28x28) and get random patches (8x8). Then use autoencoders to learn the common features of the patches (features = hidden units; approximately 100, for example). Then apply features filters to the input images and do convolution. Am I correct?

I am confused because sometime the literature state only using like, e.g. 8, filters, but in my case I have 100.

Comment: What's the CNN's output? I.e. what's the learning task?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt let say the output is classifying 10 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolutional filters are usually trained along with the rest of the network weights. The Tensorflow tutorial is a good place to start understanding convolutional neural networks in practice. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/get_started/mnist/beginners

Comment: Google recently has also released this: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/practica/image-classification/?utm_source=keyword-blog&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=ica-practicum&utm_term=&utm_content=ica-practicum