# Regress 4 values based on an input matrix with shape of (16,5)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, multivariate-regression, softmax

**Problem:** I need to regress 4 values (which quantify how much a user likes a specific topic). I am performing simulations, so I know the ground truth (the real 4 values of the preferences)

**Input Data** the system shows each time a screen to the user that contains 16 images (4 for each topic). Images have 5 features.

**Desidered OutPut** in my mind I need to input all the shown screens (each screen contains 16 imgs=n_imgs with 5 features = n_feat) and output the 4values.

**ISSUE** the input is a matrix (n_imgs x n_feat) so my question is, which type of algorithm shoud I use for this type of task? The problem is that the 4 vlaues must be predicted togheter.

Comment: Images as inputs and the [tag:machine-learning] tag suggest that the obvious approach is to use a convolutional neural network with 4 output neurons. Is there some reason that this is not a suitable solution?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about this architecture too. The strong point for CNN is that in this way I can take into account the topology of the screen (and the images' features too). 
My only concern with CNN in this case is the design of the filter.  But I will try this for sure. In this cas the filter size should be 1,n (cause it will take into account each image per time?)

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd design filters. Usually, filters are trained. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120939/how-do-we-get-define-filters-in-convolutional-neural-networks/349424#349424 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362785/why-convoloution-neural-net-have-to-find-filter-values or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472961/how-many-total-numbers-of-filters-are-there-in-conv2d

Comment: Apologize for the wrong term. I was reasoning about filter size.

Comment: Yes, choosing a good number of filters and the optimal size involves some amount of hyper-parameter tuning in general.